# Adding a property in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I have been working on adding properties to my Google Analytics account, I have been stuck with this for more than 24 hrs now, and I have no idea on what I am doing wrong... every time I try to [create a Web property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert) it returns a `403 (insufficient permission)` error.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$accountName = "xxxxxxxxxxxcl@developer.gserviceaccount.com";// Email Address
$p12 = $applicationPath."/google-api-php-client-master/API-xxxxx-xxxxxxx.p12";
$client->setScopes(array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users'
));
$client->setApplicationName('My App Sample');
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxcl.apps.googleusercontent.com');// Client Id
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                    $accountName,
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'),
                        file_get_contents($p12), 'xxxxxxxx')
                  );

$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

try {
 $property = new Google_Service_Analytics_Webproperty();
 $property->setName('sample-property');
 $analytics->management_webproperties->insert('123456', $property);// 123456 my View Id     
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
 print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
        . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();               
} catch (apiException $e) {
print 'There was a general API error '
    . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried everything but I keep getting the (`403) Insufficient Permission` error. someone please point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send Account id not view id.

```
$analytics->management_webproperties->insert('123456', $property);// 123456 my View Id
```

**Have you applied for Beta access?**

> Beta Access: 
>   Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features, request access to the beta.

Request Access form: [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform)

**Required field**

If you have been grated beta access you might want to try posting on the beta forum I cant remember if there was anyone there with PHP code.  But I think setWebsiteUrl might be required as part of the Property body.  But it doesn't appear to be documented for PHP that it is I will have to test that.

**Service Account**

It also appears that you are using a service account,  did you give the service account write access at the account level `to the Google Analytics Account you are trying to create a new web property for`?  I did a test and you can use insert with a service account that has been grated access.

[image: ServiceAccountSetup]

Comment: @DalmTo yes I have applied for Beta access and have got a confirmation for that.
I also tried `setWebsiteUrl` but I am getting the same error.
for service account, did you mean adding the `@developer.gserviceaccount.com` in the admin->User Management add user, if yes, I did that too and have added all privileges to it.

Comment: Think I found your problem // 123456 my View Id  That needs to be the account id.

Comment: @DalmTo I changed it with my account id but the error is the same.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for your replies, but unfortunately it is still giving the same error, I had registered GA for one domain but I have written this code for adding properties in another domain, does that effect anything?

Comment: You can only add properties to the domain that the service account has been given access to.  I uploaded a picture. My service account thats access to create accounts for that one Analytics Account not others.

Comment: @DalmTo I have written this code on another domain but I have registered for another domain, do I have to write this code to add properties on the same domain that I have registered GA for?

Comment: It doesn't matter what "server" it runs from what matters is that the Service account has been Granted access to the Google Analytics Account that you want to write to.  If your new domain has a new Google Analytics account then you are going to have to grant it access to that Google Analytics Account.  (Google analytics account set up for your new domain, Not login to Google Analytics)